# The wcscoll function, is marked as poisoned, what do I do?

Tags: c, macos, darwin, widechar

On Mac Os X 10.6.8 I can't compile code using wchar_t functions from the standard library until I have resolved this.

The wcscoll function, together with a bunch of others:

> **inttypes.h**:#pragma GCC poison wcstoimax wcstoumax
>   **stdlib.h**:#pragma GCC poison mbstowcs mbtowc wcstombs wctomb
>   **wchar.h**:#pragma GCC poison fgetws fputwc fputws fwprintf fwscanf mbrtowc mbsnrtowcs >mbsrtowcs putwc putwchar swprintf swscanf vfwprintf vfwscanf vswprintf vswscanf vwprintf >vwscanf wcrtomb wcscat wcschr wcscmp wcscoll wcscpy wcscspn wcsftime wcsftime wcslcat >wcslcpy wcslen wcsncat wcsncmp wcsncpy wcsnrtombs wcspbrk wcsrchr wcsrtombs wcsspn wcsstr >wcstod wcstof wcstok wcstol wcstold wcstoll wcstoul wcstoull wcswidth wcsxfrm wcwidth >wmemchr wmemcmp wmemcpy wmemmove wmemset wprintf wscanf

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <locale.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
extern  int  errno; 
int main(void)
{
wchar_t  pwcs1[3]={L"ØL"}, pwcs2[3]={L"Ål"};
size_t   n;
(void)setlocale(LC_ALL,  "");

 /*    set it to zero for checking errors on wcscoll    */
 errno  =  0;
/*
 **    Let pwcs1 and pwcs2 be two wide character strings to
 **    compare.
 */
 /* n  =  wcscmp(pwcs1, pwcs2); */
 n  =  wcscoll(pwcs1, pwcs2); 
     /*
     **    If errno is set then it indicates some
     **    collation error.
     */
if (n < 0 ) {
    printf("%s\n","Øl mindre en Ål" );
} else if (n == 0) {
    printf("%s\n","Øl lik Ål" );
} else {
    printf("%s\n","Øl større en Ål" );
}

 if(errno  !=  0){
     /*  error has occurred... handle error ...*/
 }
}
```

How do I resolve this?
I am a little bit reluctant to mess with the standard library. But I guess I **maybe** can compile the GNU C library, if Apple hasn't a fix for it? Or is there any other suitable alternatives amongst libraries for handling wide characters (Utf-8).

I am porting something ancient, so I really need to use ncurses, and in order to use ncurses, I need wide characters! :)

Edit: The standard includepath should, as I have understood it be /usr/include. I have been through the include directories of the SDK's I have, and a grep through the header files there reveals the same poison pragma's, as did the latest tarball from http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Libc/

**Edit++**

Hindsightly, those pragmas are there for a reason, and I was looking for alternatives, so right now, I am trying to build glibc, just downloaded, and I have inspected the headers, which are without any "GCC poison" pragmas.

Having read up a little bit, in the configure file of glibc, I guess that isn't an easy option. I guess I'll have to dissect something that works with utf-8 and uses ncurses on mac  osX to figure out how.

It might be that I am just overlooking an easy solution. But ncurses falls back on 7-bit ascii, and that is my problem. My goal is to render utf-8 language specific characters, while using ncurses. I need to be able to sort since the format is "propritary" with indexing, forking out a system call to sort records is no option. I also need to be able to know how many codepoints that are in a string of some kind for  field-editing, insertion and removal of characters from the display with ncurses.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste some code snippets? as well as the error code.

Comment: Hello. For some reason, that error just disappeared, but the function still just produces gibberish! When I compare "Øl" to "År" I get the result of 1, signifying that Øl is greater than År. I have set the locale LC_ALL to no_No-UTF-8. SO there should be no doubt. I have added the code example, that for mysterious reasons started to work, but produce errounous results above.

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems that the ICU library looks promising: I think I will pursue a solution with the ICU library, that as far as I know are shipped with Mac Os X. http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/